# Plotly or geom_smooth get lost date format?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, tidyverse

I have multiple time-series plots. An example plot and code can be found below. I construct the plot using `ggplot2` and make it interactive using `ggplotly()`.

However, date format on the smoothed curve get lost. Interactive chart shows date as some numeric values.

How can I fix the problem?

Thank you very much

[image]

```
structure(list(Date = structure(c(15736, 15764, 15795, 15825, 
15856, 15886), class = "Date"), CLI = c(99.93, 100.3, 100.96, 
100.71, 100.62, 101.15)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))


plot5 <- df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Date, y = CLI))+
  geom_line(size = 0.5, alpha = 0.75, show.legend = FALSE, color = "steelblue4")+
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "6 month", date_labels =  "%m/%y")+
  theme_pander()+
  geom_line(stat='smooth', method = "glm", alpha=0.5, color = "firebrick2", formula = y ~ poly(x, 5))+
  geom_ribbon(stat='smooth',method = "glm", se=TRUE,formula = y ~ poly(x, 5), alpha=0.01)+
  labs(x = "Date",
       y = "Composite Leading Indicator")
ggplotly(plot5)
```

Comment: Please consider adding sample data using `dput(df)` to reproduce the problem

Comment: @VishalA. Hi, I attached it the dput() output. Please let me know if the format is not correct. Thanks.

Comment: What you mean by date format get lost?  On the axis or do you mean the date format in the tooltip?  In the last case have a look at this related issue and solution: [ggplotly showing numbers instead of date labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70202425/ggplotly-showing-numbers-instead-of-date-labels/70204746#70204746)

Comment: Hi @stefan, I mean the tooltip. For the blue curve, the tooltip shows date properly. But it becomes a number for the smoothed (red) curve.

Answer (score 1):

Adapting my answer on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70204746/12993861) post to your case one option to get the date format in the tooltip would be to make use of the `text` aesthetic to manually create the tooltip and convert the numbers to proper dates like so:

```
plot <- df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Date, y = CLI)) +
  geom_line(size = 0.5, alpha = 0.75, show.legend = FALSE, color = "steelblue4") +
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%m/%y") +
  # theme_pander()+
  geom_line(aes(text = paste(
    "date: ", as.Date(..x.., origin = "1970-01-01"), "<br>",
    "y:", ..y..
  )), stat = "smooth", method = "glm", alpha = 0.5, color = "firebrick2", formula = y ~ poly(x, 5)) +
  geom_ribbon(stat = "smooth", method = "glm", se = TRUE, formula = y ~ poly(x, 5), alpha = 0.01) +
  labs(
    x = "Date",
    y = "Composite Leading Indicator"
  )
ggplotly(plot, tooltip = c("text"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I tried it. It fixed the problem but caused the tooltip for the blue curve to get lost. So, I just copied the `aes(text = "..")` part into the first `geom_line`. The tooltip for both curves works properly now. But, I am curious if there is a better way to do that.

Comment: Aw. Sorry. Maybe there is an easier or out-of-the-box approach. But my guess is that there isn't.